# Switching XKB group programmatically

Tags: xkb

Is there a way to switch group programmatically, without actually pressing a key that's bound to something like `ISO_First_Group`?  I tried `xdotool key ISO_First_Group`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xkb-switch](https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch).

Example:

```
$ setxkbmap it,us
$ # print the current group
$ xkb-switch
it
$ # next group
$ xkb-switch --next
$ xkb-switch
us
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103199/136104)

Comment: This is not switching groups, it's switching layouts.

Comment: @MikaelF `setxkbmap it,us` is a setup with two layouts or two groups—they’re really the same, technically speaking.

Comment: But they're not. For example, `it` can contain up to four "groups". Groups are layouts within layouts, and as such, they're inaccessible from outside xkb. This is why keysim `ISO_Next_Group` (or xkb `action` `SetGroup()`) won't shift from  `it` to `us`, but rather willl cycle between groups within `it`.

Comment: @MikaelF `ISO_Next_Group` will cycle between layouts if you have a setup with two layouts where each of the two layouts just use one group.  Maybe things are different for layouts with multiple groups, but in my experience Xkb will treat (say) two layouts with two layouts each as four groups.  And the two layouts will probably step on each others toes.  But hey, maybe I’m working on old information (experience) and Xkb has gotten a great upgrade recently.

Comment: I used a `setxkbmap x,y` setup for a while and while I didn’t use `ISO_Next_Group`, I did use the keys to lock to group 1 and 2 (`ISO_Lock_Group1` or whatever they’re called).  And they did lock to those “groups” or “layouts”.  But for more advanced setups I don’t know, maybe I’m totally off base there.  But I don’t think most people use multiple layouts _and_ multiple groups within those layouts.